# Cannot set "setAsEdge" in Box2D on iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

This code will create lines around the iPhone screen, but the bottom line should be in the middle (I need to change the .y but I don't know how).
How to do that?

And can someone explain these "setAsEdge" methods to me?

```
// Define the ground body.
b2BodyDef groundBodyDef;
groundBodyDef.position.Set(0,0); // bottom-left corner

// Call the body factory which allocates memory for the ground body
// from a pool and creates the ground box shape (also from a pool).
// The body is also added to the world.
b2Body* groundBody = world->CreateBody(&groundBodyDef);

// Define the ground box shape.
b2PolygonShape groundBox;       

// bottom
groundBox.SetAsEdge(b2Vec2(0,0), b2Vec2(screenSize.width/PTM_RATIO,0));
groundBody->CreateFixture(&groundBox,0);

// top
groundBox.SetAsEdge(b2Vec2(0,screenSize.height/PTM_RATIO), b2Vec2(screenSize.width/PTM_RATIO,screenSize.height/PTM_RATIO));
groundBody->CreateFixture(&groundBox,0);

// left
groundBox.SetAsEdge(b2Vec2(0,screenSize.height/PTM_RATIO), b2Vec2(0,0));
groundBody->CreateFixture(&groundBox,0);

// right
groundBox.SetAsEdge(b2Vec2(screenSize.width/PTM_RATIO,screenSize.height/PTM_RATIO), b2Vec2(screenSize.width/PTM_RATIO,0));
groundBody->CreateFixture(&groundBox,0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// bottom

float screenMid = screenSize.height/2;  // Y axis on screen middle

        groundBox.SetAsEdge(b2Vec2(0,screenMid/PTM_RATIO),b2Vec2(screenSize.width/PTM_RATIO,screenMid/PTM_RATIO));
```

This will shift your bottom line to screen middle.
The SetAsEdge method takes two points and draw a line from point-1 to point-2. In above statement the point one is "b2Vec2(0,screenMid/PTM_RATIO)". Where 0 is the x-axis and screenMid is the y-axis of first point. Same goes with the second point.

You have to divide every point by PTM_RATIO to translate it into box2d coordinates.